# How can I reference my Java Enum without specifying its type

Tags: java, enums

I have a class that defines its own enum like this:

```
public class Test
{
    enum MyEnum{E1, E2};

    public static void aTestMethod() {
        Test2(E1);  // << Gives "E1 cannot be resolved" in eclipse.
    }
    public Test2(MyEnum e) {}
}
```

If I specify MyEnum.E1 it works fine, but I'd really just like to have it as "E1".  Any idea how I can accomplish this, or does it have to be defined in another file for this to work?

CONCLUSION:
I hadn't been able to get the syntax for the import correct.  Since several answers suggested this was possible, I'm going to select the one that gave me the syntax I needed and upvote the others.

By the way, a REALLY STRANGE part of this (before I got the static import to work), a switch statement I'd written that used the enum did not allow the enum to be prefixed by its type--all the rest of the code required it.  Hurt my head.

Comment: Regarding the "really strange" behavior on the switch statements: Java does this on all enums in a switch statement. Since you know what type you're switching on, they figure there's no reason to make you specify the type again in every case block. http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: I guess what got to me is that it would not allow the Enum type prefix.  Everywhere else prefixing is either required (if not imported) or optional.

Comment: I agree with you in reference to the `switch` inconsistency, makes less experienced Java programmers scratch their heads.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Actually, you can do a [static import](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html) of a nested enum. The code below compiles fine:

```
package mypackage;

import static mypackage.Test.MyEnum.*;

public class Test
{
    enum MyEnum{E1, E2};

    public static void aTestMethod() {
        Test2(E1);  
    }

    public static void Test2(MyEnum e) {}
}
```

Comment: I alluded to this as a solution in my question, but I'd really rather not do that.  The enums are only used inside this one file.  It just seems strange that this doesn't just automatically work.

Comment: Although you have to use a static import, you do not need to define it in its own class.

Comment: I tried in a few ways and can't get the static import to resolve correctly when it refers to a class inside the class doing the import.

Comment: @Yishai Yeah, I noticed that when doing some testing.

Comment: @Bill K weird, are you sure you tried `import static mypackage.Test.MyEnum.*;`?

Comment: @Bill K, why do you think it should automatically work?  How would you expect this to work then?

class A { enum B {X,Y}; enum C {X,Z}; }

Comment: @Pascal Is there any given reason why the enum has to be default? I would like the enum to be private, as no one else needs access to it. However, a private enum can't be imported, even though it's in the same file. Thoughts?

Comment: This solution works only because MyEnum is visible outside of Test.  Solution will not work if MyEnum is, e.g., private.

Comment: This works also with normal enums, not only nested ones, at least as of Java 7.

Comment: Do not forget the last part, symbols ".*" in "import static mypackage.Test.MyEnum.*;" as I did!

Comment: The word _nested_ should be underlined. Funny that you can not static import a non nested enum. You can do it in Groovy, but in my Eclipse and IntelliJ IDEs I have the same problem as above: no autocompletion for enums, not even if I use the enum type as in TYPE.VA...

Answer (score 18):

You can do a static import on a nested class:

```
import static apackage.Test.Enum.*;
```

Answer (score 11):

The Test class has to be defined in a package to be importable.

With package defined in `Test` (**IT WORKS**):

```
package mypackage;
```

You can use:

```
import static mypackage.Test.MyEnum.*;
```

Without package defined, you cannot use (**DOES NOT WORK**):

```
import static Test.MyEnum.*;
```

Comment: Great point >> `Without package defined, you cannot use (DOES NOT WORK):`