# Import cannot be resolved?

Tags: java, import, enums

So right now, I have a Brick.java which contains a Levels enum that I want to use in BreakoutCourt.java, which is contained in the same package, which is (default package).

When I write import Brick.level; in BreakoutCourt , I get a message that says The Import Brick Cannot Be Resolved. I get that message even if I write import static Brick.Level!

The levels enum contained in Brick.java looks like this:

```
public class Brick {
   public static final int BWIDTH = 60;
   public static final int BHEIGHT = 20;
   private int xPos, yPos; 
   private Level brickLevel;

    //This sets up the different levels of bricks.
   enum Level{
    LUNATIC (4, 40, Color.MAGENTA),
    HARD (3, 30, Color.PINK), 
    MEDIUM (2, 20, Color.BLUE),
    EASY (1, 10, Color.CYAN),
    DEAD (0, 0, Color.WHITE);
    private int hitpoints;
    private int points;
    private Color color;

    Level(int hitpoints, int points, Color color){
        this.hitpoints = hitpoints;
        this.points = points;
        this.color=color;
        }
    public int getPoints(){
        return points;
        }
    public Color getColor(){
        return color;
        }
}

//rest of brick class goes under the enum
```

And I use it in BreakoutCourt like this:

```
    //Generates the bricks.
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i){
        ArrayList<Brick> temp = new ArrayList<Brick>();
        Level rowColor = null;
        switch(i){
        //There are two rows per type of brick.
            case 0:
            case 1:
                rowColor = Level.EASY;
                break;
            case 2:
            case 3:
                rowColor = Level.HARD;
                break;
            case 4:
            case 5:
                rowColor = Level.LUNATIC;
                break;
            case 6:
            case 7:
            default:
                rowColor = Level.MEDIUM;
                break;
        }
        for(int j = 0; j < numBrick; j++){
            Brick tempBrick = new Brick((j * Brick.BWIDTH), ((i+2) * Brick.BHEIGHT), rowColor);
            temp.add(tempBrick);
        }
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to import a member of a class, you need to use a [static import](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html). So you could do:

```
import static Brick.Level;
```

Be careful though. Static imports should be used sparingly, as noted by that linked page. Another way to do it without a static import is to use the outer class name. For example: `Brick.Level.LUNATIC` The reason is that in a larger project you might have multiple classes with a Level enum, and you would have to look at the import to see which one is being used.

Comment: Hm, I'm still getting an import cannot be resolved. The enum is supposed to be in the public class, right?

Comment: Do you have a package statement at the top of Brick.java?

Answer (score 0):

How are you importing Enum ?

You should have an import statement like

```
import static Brick.Level
```

Related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677037/how-can-i-reference-my-java-enum-without-specifying-its-type)