# Efficiently Check Multiple Conditions

Tags: java, performance, conditional-statements

I've got a situation in which I need to check multiple conditions, where every combination has a different outcome. In my specific condition, I've got 2 variables, which are enum types, that can each be 2 different values.

```
enum Enum1
{
    COND_1,
    COND_2
}
enum EnumA
{
    COND_A,
    COND_B
}
Enum1 var1;
EnumA varA;
```

This gives me 4 possible conditions, which requires 4 different outcomes. I've come up with a few different ways of doing this, either using if statements or switch statements:

```
if(var1 == Enum1.COND_1 && varA == EnumA.COND_A)
{
    // Code
}
else if(var1 == Enum1.COND_1 && varA == EnumA.COND_B)
{
    // Code
}
else if(var1 == Enum1.COND_2 && varA == EnumA.COND_A)
{
    // Code
}
else if(var1 == Enum1.COND_2 && varA == EnumA.COND_B)
{
    // Code
}
```

Or:

```
switch(var1)
{
    case COND_1:
        switch(varA)
        {
            case COND_A:
                // Code
                break;
            case COND_B:
                // Code
                break;
        }
        break;
    case COND_2:
        switch(varA)
        {
            case COND_A:
                // Code
                break;
            case COND_B:
                // Code
                break;
        }
        break;
}
```

I've thought of others, but don't want to fill this up with code :P I'd like to know what the best way to do this is. I think the switch is a bit easier to read, but the ifs are shorter. I think it'd be really cool if switches could have multiple conditions, but I haven't heard of it. This also begs the question: what's the best way to do this with an arbitrary number of variables and possible values?

Comment: If you're doing this in a *serious* manner, then you'd probably use a rules engine or other 3rd party system that would abstract all that code away.

Comment: Why do you need to check multiple conditions like that? What are you actually doing? This might be solved in a nicer way with a redesign instead of trying to decide between ifs and switches.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern

Comment: It's mainly just setting some variables. They're independent from one another, so I don't see a more elegant solution over checking the conditions.

Comment: I've talked with some other programmers in person, and they've all recommended the nested switches. I would add it as an answer, but they've been closed due to the question being opinion-based. My apologies. Thank you to those who answered!

Answer (score 13):

For your small use case I would probably go for nested `if` statements. But if you have plenty of `enum` constants, perhaps a pattern using streams could make your code easier to read and maintain (for a small performance penalty). You could solve it using a stream like this:

```
Stream.of(new Conditional(COND_1, COND_A, () -> {/* do something */}),
          new Conditional(COND_1, COND_B, () -> {/* do something */}),
          new Conditional(COND_2, COND_A, () -> {/* do something */}),
          new Conditional(COND_2, COND_B, () -> {/* do something */}))
      .filter(x -> x.test(var1, varA))
      .findAny()
      .ifPresent(Conditional::run);
```

That would require a supporting class:

```
class Conditional implements BiPredicate<Enum1, EnumA>, Runnable
{
    private final Enum1 var1;
    private final EnumA varA;
    private final Runnable runnable;

    public Conditional(Enum1 var1, EnumA varA, Runnable runnable) {
        this.var1 = var1;
        this.varA = varA;
        this.runnable = runnable;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean test(Enum1 enum1, EnumA enumA) {
        return var1 == enum1 && varA == enumA;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        runnable.run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Performance differences are probably negligible here, so I would focus on shortness and readability. So I would just simplify the `if`'s a bit by using temporary variables:

```
boolean is_1 = (var1 == Enum1.COND_1);
boolean is_A = (varA == EnumA.COND_A);

if(is_1 && is_A)
{
    // Code
}
else if(is_1 && !is_A)
{
    // Code
}
else if(!is_1 && is_A)
{
    // Code
}
else if(!is_1 && !is_A)
{
    // Code
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I prefer the `if` variant without nesting, since it is short and you have all the conditions in one line.

When stopping through the code during debugging, it can get tedious though, since you have to step over all preceding conditions, which is O(n). When executing the code, this shouldn't matter since the compiler will probably optimize the code.

There is no obvious best way, so you will have to experiment a bit.

Answer (score 3):

I definitely prefer the flat version, it could just use a little less duplication:

```
// If you can't make the variables final, make some final copies
final Enum1 var1 = Enum1.COND_2;
final EnumA varA = EnumA.COND_B;

class Tester {  // You could also make an anonymous BiPredicate<Enum1, EnumA>
    boolean t(Enum1 v1, EnumA vA) {
        return var1 == v1 && varA == vA;
    }
};

Tester tes = new Tester();

if (tes.t(Enum1.COND_1, EnumA.COND_A)) {
    // code
} else if (tes.t(Enum1.COND_1, EnumA.COND_B)) {
    // code
} else if (tes.t(Enum1.COND_2, EnumA.COND_A)) {
    // code
} else if (tes.t(Enum1.COND_2, EnumA.COND_B)) {
    // code
}
```

Run it [here](http://ideone.com/OiLZWc). You could maybe make it even shorter and less redundant by doing a [static import of the enums](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1677074) to avoid mentioning the enum names, e.g. `tes.t(COND_1, COND_B)`. Or if you're willing to give up some compile time safety you can pass a string which gets converted to the two enum values, e.g. `tes.t("COND_1 COND_A")` (the implementation is left to the reader).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe crazy idea but you could construct an int or a byte using the flags and use it in a single switch.

```
private int getIntegerStateForConditions(boolean... conditions ){
    int state = 0;
    int position = 0;
    for(boolean condition: conditions){
        if(condition){
            state = state || (1 << position++);
        }
    }
    return state;
}
```

...

```
switch(getIntegerStateForCondition((var1 == Enum1.COND_1), (var2 == EnumA.COND_A)){
    case 0: ... //both condition false
    case 1: ... //first condition true second false
    case 2: ... //first false, second true ...
}
```

...

I think this is very far from being clean code but it looks better.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would rely on bit flags in order to have only one `byte` (as you have only 4 use cases) to deal with and use a `switch` statement on this `byte` to manage all your use cases.

Something like this:

```
private static final int COND_2 = 1;
private static final int COND_B = 2;

private byte value;

public void setValue(Enum1 enum1) {
    if (enum1 == Enum1.COND_1) {
        this.value &= ~COND_2;
    } else {
        this.value |= COND_2;
    }
}

public void setValue(EnumA enumA) {
    if (enumA == EnumA.COND_A) {
        this.value &= ~COND_B;
    } else {
        this.value |= COND_B;
    }
}

public Enum1 getEnum1() {
    return (this.value & COND_2) == COND_2 ? Enum1.COND_2 : Enum1.COND_1;
}


public EnumA getEnumA() {
    return (this.value & COND_B) == COND_B ? EnumA.COND_B : EnumA.COND_A;
}
```

Then your tests would be:

```
switch (value) {
    case 0 :
        // 1-A;
        break;
    case 1 :
        // 2-A;
        break;
    case 2 :
        // 1-B;
        break;
    case 3 :
        // 2-B;
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would personally prefer this:

```
if(understandableNameInContextName1(var1, varA))
{
    // Code
}
else if(understandableNameInContextName2(var1, varA))
{
    // Code
}
else if(understandableNameInContextName3(var1, varA))
{
    // Code
}
else if(understandableNameInContextName4(var1, varA))
{
    // Code
}

private boolean understandableNameInContextName1(Object var1, Object varA){
 return (var1 == Enum1.COND_1 && varA == EnumA.COND_A);
}

private boolean understandableNameInContextName2(Object var1, Object varA){
 return (var1 == Enum1.COND_1 && varA == EnumA.COND_B);
}

private boolean understandableNameInContextName3(Object var1, Object varA){
 return (var1 == Enum1.COND_2 && varA == EnumA.COND_A);
}

private boolean understandableNameInContextName4(Object var1, Object varA){
 return (var1 == Enum1.COND_2 && varA == EnumA.COND_B);
}
```

And the names of the methods could be like, isOrderShippedAndDelivered(), isRequestSendAndAckRecieved().

The reason is that this is going to make the code a lot more readable.
Unless you have data that leads you back to these if statement there is not going to be much gain optimizing these.

See:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil

Answer (score 0):

Kind of depends on the complexity of the code and number of combinations but another option is a dictionary with the key comprising a Tuple of your enumerations and a value of a delegate to the code.