# Is this proper enum practice in Java?

Tags: java, class, oop, enums, access-modifiers

I just started learning enums in Java and although the concept seems straightforward, its application isn't really intuitive to me. I see that I can put enums inside of classes although they are classes themselves.

I also saw online some people say you can only have one enum in a class, or that you shouldn't put all enums in a single class unless they are put private.

Thus, I'm a bit confused, would this piece of code be a proper writing of enum?

Thanks.

```
public class AirCraft 
{
    private AirType type;
    private AirFixTime maintainTime;
    
    private enum AirType
    {
        HELICOPTER,
        AIRLINE,
        BALLOON,
        GLIDER;
    }
    
    private enum AirFixTime
    {
        WEEKLY,
        MONTHLY,
        YEARLY;
    }
}
```

Comment: It will surely work, but what is the use of declaring them `private`? The fields referencing them can't be retrieved or set by anyone using your `AirCraft` class.

Comment: @Lino-Votedon'tsayThanks you're right, that wouldn't make much sense for them to be private. Do you think that these enum classes being inside the AirCraft class is okay though? Or should they be in class files of their own?

Comment: Inner classes/enums only make sense when they are used together with the enclosing class (e.g. they are tightly coupled and really only make sense when used together). Your `AirType` would make sense to be in your class, but `AirFixTime` could aswell be used for different classes.

Comment: To get started, I would always put classes and enums in their own file. Not private classes and no private enums. They can mess up your code quickly and there is absolutely no need. If you want to keep order in your program and if you want to manage access to certain classes or enums, then put them in packages and make the them package `protected` (instead of public)

Comment: Yes, it is possible and it works (just like you can have inner classes and nested static classes), but whether or not it is the 'right' choice is a matter of opinion.

Comment: This Question **should be reopened**. Being closed for being “Opinion-based” is not appropriate here. That closing rule is designed to avoid open-ended long-winded discussions going on and on without resolution. This Question can be neatly answered with brief explanation.

Comment: @BasilBourque I'm trusting you on that assumption

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a choice of three places to put an enum definition.

- Class of its own.
- Nested within another class.
- Locally, within a method (Java 16+)

## Context is key

You can place your enum definition anywhere that makes sense to you. It all depends on context.

- If your enum is meant to be used in other code, on its own, put the enum in its own class.
- If the enum really only makes sense when used within the context of a
  particular class, then nest the enum.

  - If the enum objects are used only within the parent class’ own source code, make the enum definition `private`.
  - If the enum objects might be used by outside code working with objects of the parent class, make the nested class `public`. For example, a report building class might want to sort aircraft parts by their assigned `AirCraft.Color` enum object, to gather together all the [safety-orange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safety_orange) parts.

For example, consider the `Month` and `DayOfWeek` enum classes built into Java as part of the *java.time* classes. These enum definitions live in their own separate classes because they may be used in many different contexts, without the involvement of other *java.time* classes. These enums could be used on their own in workflow apps, sales reports, accounting apps, and more.

In contrast, imagine a UI framework tracking mouse events. There we might find a `Event` enum for mouse events, defining objects named `HOVER`, `CLICKED`, and `DRAGGED`. This enum would best be housed within the `Mouse` class as it only has meaning within the context of the outer mouse-handling class.

Another example, colors.

- An enum listing all [the standard colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#CSS_colors) named in [Cascading Style Sheets (CSS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) should be in its own class, as many kinds of code may use that.
- An enum listing colors used in color-coding parts of your aircraft should be nested within the `AirCraft` class, its only sensible context.

Usages:

```
myWebPage.setBackground( CssColor.DARK_SLATE_GREY ) ;  // This enum could be used on its own with many classes in different frameworks. So define enum in a separate class..

myAircraft.getEmergencyStopButton().setColor( AirCraft.Color.SAFETY_ORANGE ) ;  // This enum is only ever used in contexts using its parent class, so nest the enum definition.
```

If nesting, think about your naming. I would likely name the enum `Color` rather than `AircraftColor`, because the nested notation `AirCraft.Color.x` makes clear the context. On the other hand, some folks like to use a `static import` to be able to use [`Color.x` without the `AirCraft.` prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1677037/642706) (not my preference).

### Local enums

New in Java 16 will be local enums (previewed in Java 15). That means enums defined within a method.

This new feature seems to be documented only as a mention within the new Records feature: [*JEP 384: Records (Second Preview)*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/384).

```
private void demoLocalEnum ( )
{
    enum Color { PURPLE , SAFETY_ORANGE }
    System.out.println( Color.PURPLE ) ;
}
```

As we can see in this screenshot, the enum only exists within the method containing its declaration. A sibling method on the same class does not know of the enum’s existence. In this example, trying to use the enum within another method generates an error within the IDE’s code editor.

[image: Screenshot of error "Cannot resolve symbol 'Color'" caused by trying to use in an enum defined locally in another method.]

Use this where your enum makes sense only within one chunk of code. If your enum is only used within a single method, then declaring it as a nested class draws undue attention. Being tucked away inside that method is more tidy.

Comment: Thanks. I will put my enum classes nested inside my AirCraft class then. I'm guessing that putting them as default/private/public should not really make a different since I'm only using them through AirCraft class right?

Comment: @HelloWorld I just added more bullets on that point. A general rule: Make everything `private` until you have a known use-case demanding otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

Technically, your code is properly written. Uses of enums depends of the functionality. Remember that the access modifiers are used to manage what you going to share or show to others. Right now your code is correct if the enums is going to be used just inside AirCraft.

Take a look at [this](https://crunchify.com/why-and-for-what-should-i-use-enum-java-enum-examples/)